# julia Cxx package different behavior when in module

Tags: c++, julia

I'm using Julia 1.1.1, and version 0.3.2 of Cxx. I'm finding that I'm getting an error when I call icxx"" from within a module I've defined, but not when I'm calling it in the REPL. In the REPL I have:

```
using Cxx

function xformVectors()

cxx"""
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Summer {
public:
    Summer() {}
    std::vector<int> compute_sum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &input) {
        std::vector<int> result(input.size(), 0);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != input.size(); ++i) {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j != input[i].size(); ++j) {
               result[i] += input[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
"""
    as = [rand(1:10,5), rand(1:10,6)]
    x = convert(cxxt"std::vector< std::vector< int > >", as)
    summer = @cxxnew Summer()
    cxx_v = icxx"$summer->compute_sum($x);"
    for v in cxx_v
        println(collect(v))
    end

end
```

If I then call `xformVectors()`, it writes out a couple of integers and exits (the expected behavior). If I use Pkg.generate() to wrap this code in a module, and then call `xformVectors()`, I get a fatal error:

```
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 36-element Array{Tuple{AbstractString,Symbol,Int64,Int64,Bool},1} at index [37]
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{Tuple{AbstractString,Symbol,Int64,Int64,Bool},1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:729
 [2] #s37#70 at /home/jov9025/.julia/packages/Cxx/vxYtJ/src/cxxstr.jl:705 [inlined]
 [3] #s37#70(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at ./none:0
 [4] (::Core.GeneratedFunctionStub)(::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./boot.jl:522
 [5] xformVectors() at /home/jov9025/sandbox/julia/Vector2Vector.jl/src/Vector2Vector.jl:30
 [6] top-level scope at none:0
```

If, in the REPL, I include the source file (`include("src/Vector2Vector.jl"`) and then call `Vector2Vector.xformVectors()`, it runs without complaint.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It's very hard to say what's going on when you don't include the code that actually causes the error

Comment: The c++ code contained in the cxx""" """ string is compiled by Cxx, and the 'Summer' class is available to be constructed (hence the @cxxnew Summer() line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in my code where the error originated was:

```
cxx_v = icxx"$summer->compute_sum($x);"
```

I still don't understand what the problem was with icxx"", but I don't actually need to use it in this sample (or in my real code). I can just use the `@cxx` macro, and voila, no crash:

```
cxx_v = @cxx compute_sum(x)
```

So, I may have been asking the wrong question (although I think it's an interesting one).

Revisiting this in January 2020: with version 0.3.3 of Cxx, the code executes fine with the original icxx"" line in the REPL.